# initializationError(examples.Example1): No runnable methods - JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit5

I am getting this error when I run my TestRunner class (JUnit 5), it is the simple code.

Example1.java class contains simple 2 method validating strings are equal or not

**Example1.java**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class Example1 {

@Test
public void test1() {
    String res = "JUnit 5";
    Assertions.assertEquals(res, "JUnit 5", "This test case Passes");
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    String res = "JUnit 5";
    Assertions.assertEquals(res, "Hello World..!!!", "This test case Failed");
}
}
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(examples.Example1.class);

      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
          System.out.println(failure.toString());
       }

       System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());

}

}
```

**Output -**
initializationError(examples.Example1): No runnable methods
false

Comment: You're using the JUnit 4 engine to try and run JUnit 5 tests.

Comment: Use the Platform ConsoleLauncher https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher or roll your own launcher via https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api